# Do incoming wires to my bank account get reported to the IRS?

Tags: irs, wire-transfer

If I wire a large amount of money from an online exchange to my bank account, will it get reported to the IRS?

The money is coming from a Crypto trading exchange.

Edit: this question is not related to the 2013 loan question answered below.

Comment: What is the source of the funds?

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed. Answers from 2013 regarding loan proceeds don't necessarily apply in 2021 to transfers from online exchanges.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Crypto trading exchange.

Comment: @jack,the issue is whether electronic transfers in general are reported to the IRS, and the answer is STILL no, even in 2021.  See https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/cash-payment-report-helps-government-combat-money-laundering

Comment: The subject of the posting you linked to is Form 8300, which indeed is probably inapplicable. The transfer may still be reported - not to the IRS necessarily, but to the OCC on a SAR, if that requirement is triggered.  The far more important issue here, though, is not so much OP's transfer from his crypto account to his bank account - the very fact the question is asked indicates to me that the existence of the crypto account itself has probably not been reported (on FBAR, for example) and the income from the account may have not been declared. All hypothetical, obviously.

Comment: (assuming US) @JackFleeting+ not all crypto exchanges are foreign, and if the cash is from recent sales and wasn't there before Dec 31, it's not _yet_ reportable on FBAR. Accounts containing (only) crypto haven't been reportable, although FinCEN recently announced they intend to propose to change that. However _profits_ on trading crypto are capital gains, which must be reported (to IRS) in the year realized, regardless of whether the resulting cash is left on deposit or reinvested or whatever.

Comment: U.S. Treasury announced new policy today about reporting transfers of $10k or more to/from crypto brokers and exchanges.